# System.IO.File.Delete invalid characters

Tags: c#, file-io, invalid-characters

I'm trying to delete all files in a directory by doing this:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(directoriodestino_imagenes + @"\*.*");
```

Where, `directoriodestino_imagenes = "C:\\dcm\\patients\\NAME_LASTNAME\\DCM\\"`.

And I get this:

> {"Illegal characters in path."}

Any hints what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Quoting from the ONLINE REFERENCE: `path: The name of the file to be deleted. Wildcard characters are not supported.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the wildcard character. You cannot delete multiple files using Delete method. You either need to delete the whole folder (look at the Delete folder method at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) or just remove them one by one. E.g. like in [Deleting multiple files with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807209/deleting-multiple-files-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to delete Files in a folder. Here is how I do it.

```
 string directory = @"C:\File Downloader\DownloadedFile\";
 string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(directory); // get all files in the folder.
 foreach (string fileName in file )
 File.Delete(fileName );
```