# Delete files in temp folder in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, delete-file, temp

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 and I am using C#. So I created Windows Form and I added a button named "button1". What I am trying to do is: when user clicks a button, the **content of folder**, named ( let´s say ) temp, located in C:/temp, is deleted, but the **temp folder still remains**.

I have tried to use this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "del /q/f/s %TEMP%\* ";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```

But I was told that this method is useful so I didn't use it anymore. And it also kept throwing an exception: "Unrecognized escape sequence". 
I was also told I should use System.IO namespace, I also tried to look for tutorials but I didn't find them useful.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807209/deleting-multiple-files-with-wildcard

Comment: Thanks, but what I am actually trying to do is to delete ALL files in certain folder, regardless on their extension.

Comment: use ''**.**'' as file name

Comment: Why are you not using .net framework? `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`

Comment: What does "." stands for? How do i define a folder in which i want to delete these files.

Comment: @T.S. what is a framework? I think i am using 4.6 framework

Comment: should be "\*.\*", I can't write it.

Comment: @Andrey so basically asterisk is a folder, asterics is a file located in this folder?

Comment: asterics is mask, folder is dot.

Comment: "\*.\*" means all files. I find a way to write it as it should be.

Comment: "what is a framework?" - why are you even asking questions here... not sure... I just gave you answer how to delete directory - go grab it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If youre looking to delete all files within the temp folder i would do something like this

```
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp");
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir.ToString()))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
```

or, if you are looking to delete certain files or types use something like this

```
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

string userName = Environment.UserName;

```
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\"+userName+ "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp");
        var d = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\Temp");
       foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(d.ToString()))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw it says Unrecognized Escape Sequence cause you had a slash the wrong way around.
This is how it should be:

```
string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "del /q/f/s %TEMP%/* ";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```