# System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path. when deleting a file using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system, illegal-characters

I'm creating a small program in C# to delete the files that start with the word `"python".exe` in this directory

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\
```

I used this code

```
string filetoDelete = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps" + @"\\*python*.exe";
File.Delete(filetoDelete);
```

when I run the program it gives me this error message

> System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'

and the red X is marked next to `File.Delete(filetoDelete);`
how do I fix this?

Comment: [Wildcard characters are not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-5.0), use Directory.EnumerateFiles().

Comment: @HansPassant is right: [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8807273/4166522) show how to do what he says.